# Why was I banned for using one of the site features to close my own question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, low-quality

I was banned from asking more questions in the community because I had closed one of my own questions.

I truly respect the way the community is trying to keep the quality of questions high. That's why, when I got downvoted instead of receiving answers on one of my questions, I quickly deleted it. I did this for two reasons.

First, the system gives me the ability and the right to do so. If the feature isn't meant to be used, why don't you disable deleting questions similar to how the site prevents changing voting after a while? Why should I have been banned from asking more questions because I had used my rights?

Second, I wanted to keep my reputation and question quality on the site, which I am trying to preserve in the community, and which you are looking for, using the features you already gave me to deleting my questions. I wanted to do this because I realized that it was a low quality question.

I suggest to disable the automatic banning system and return to "vote to close" from some of the community members. I think it is enough for me and for another to be asked to close their own questions because it is a low quality question. I suggest that we encourage users to delete their own low quality questions or downvote, if doing so is the best thing for the community.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works exactly since privileges are different for mods, but didn't you receive any kind of message upon deleting your post? Note: You are currently *not* banned.

Comment: nope, when I was banned for too long time, I contact the support team recently and they tell the ban was lifted. but I am still cant feel safe ;)

Comment: Were you prevented from asking new question or was your account actually suspended?  There is a huge difference.

Comment: Deletion might have been the trigger, but you deleted for a reason. The problem may have had more to do with a pattern of submitting low-quality questions that were not well-received by the community (downvoted). You might have had a question ban whether you deleted them or not. Spend a little time reviewing site resources on how to ask good questions and look at examples of upvoted questions. You could also ask for input on improving a question on Root Access (DragonLord has a dedicated chat room for that but it keeps closing due to low traffic).

Answer (score 5):

> I suggest that we encourage users to delete their own low quality questions or downvote, if doing so is the best thing for the community.

No, what we really should do is getting users to *improve* their questions.

We gain nothing from deleted posts. We *do* gain a lot from people asking good questions and others posting great answers.

Looking at your [latest question](https://superuser.com/questions/896788/how-do-i-adjust-my-printable-margin-and-i-distribute-equally-over-the-printed-pa), it's really missing lots of details. Operating system, printer make and model, driver version, et cetera. You also received a few comments asking for that kind of information.

If you are really interested in an answer and (hopefully) a solution to a real issue you're having, you should make an effort to provide all kinds of information others request from you. They (and others) will probably need that information to be able to help you properly.

Not responding—especially with a downvoted question—will just leave the question abandoned. Not properly tagged or lacking essential information, it will be auto-deleted when it's downvoted with a low number of views. Whether you're going to let that happen eventually, or trigger that deletion yourself, does not really matter.

If there really is no message informing people about possible negative side effects of self-deleted questions, then I agree there should be a warning and some way to encourage them to improve questions before abandoning them.

However, I am pretty certain that when you're about to become banned, and you're trying to post a new question, you *will* get a message about your latest questions not being received well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had an experience when improving my question with much more details, I got a request to close the question as it is appears to be a Technical support question. specially when mentioning the hardware model. I think this is one of the points you mentioned in the help center. and sure I need help, that is the reason I am here! I am telling you the truth. I don't come here asking a question if there is no answers in any place over the web. and when I came trying to fix my problem I got disappointed! to prove what I mean I will edit my last question.

Comment: The second point is (I am using my rights) there is a button and it is not dimmed and I can use it. improving the question is a part of the issue of course, but the other side is the question couldn't be improved more that that and it must be closed.

Comment: @hsawires Not everything that you *can* do is necessarily good for you or for the site. It is impossible to design a web app with this amount of complexity while making it completely impossible for someone to do something that is considered a mistake. We rely on users to exercise good judgment and to understand site rules in order to continue contributing to the site. There may be situations where deleting your own question is the correct thing to do, so we can't automatically distinguish those situations from ones such as yours, so we can't intelligently disable the button.

Comment: To take a real-life example: no one can watch you constantly to ensure that you never cross a street when there's a red "do not cross" sign. You are free to walk anyway, and get hit by a car. This would be a consequence of your actions. We can provide the *advice* that you should not walk, but we can't be omniscient and observe every single pedestrian to make sure that no one ever walks at a red light. Pedestrians have the *responsibility* to follow traffic rules. You have the *responsibility* to follow site rules.

Comment: In real life, people who don't follow traffic rules get hit by cars. On StackExchange sites, people who don't follow site rules are no longer allowed to post. Them's the breaks, I'm afraid. The real world has consequences for things you do in it.

Comment: @allquixotic first, thank for the reply and editing -- I behave in terms of responsibility and responsibility is not an absolute term. it is relative from a person to anther. and we all make mistakes, mistakes let us learn ... but some mistakes may cost us our lives in term of learning. after all, is it worth !! lives are chances the more you do mistakes the more you grow up and get more and more expert. and doing mistakes in your real life is a must to continue your life... Now I'd better watching more that contributing. banning is like "Game over" don't let you "learn".

Comment: @hsawires - It takes multiple low-quality questions to be bared from asking new questions.  As others have pointed out you have been given input on how to improve your existing questions, and the quality of your questions have not improved, by a significant quality.